# include at the end of a header file, is it safe/good practise?

Tags: c++, include

I have been trying to write my own state machine where each state is a seperate class derived from a state base class.

Whereever I include my state_t class file (#include "state_t.h") I want all the derived state class headers to be included as well so I don't have to include them all seperatly each time I need to use the state machine or create a new state.

since "state_t" is not defined until the end of state_t.h I can only include my state files at the end of the file state_t.h. I have never written code that does this before and it seems a little odd! I could add a top-level "statemachine.h" which collects all the files together, but it seems a waste.

My question is: is it correct/safe/ok to do this? any draw-backs/issues?

**Note:** at the moment my code is all test code and its written in Qt, but it should be a straight-up c++ question.

Here is my base class (state_t.h) - **notice the #include's at the end**:

```
#ifndef STATE_T_H
#define STATE_T_H

#include <QByteArray>
#include <QDebug>

class state_t
{
public:
    state_t(QByteArray stateName);
    virtual ~state_t();
    virtual state_t * processState(int input) = 0;
    QByteArray getState();

    QByteArray name;
};

#include "teststate1.h"
#include "teststate2.h"

#endif // STATE_T_H
```

Here is a state derived class (teststate1.h):

```
#ifndef TESTSTATE1_H
#define TESTSTATE1_H

#include "state_t.h"

class testState1 : public state_t
{
public:
    testState1();
    state_t *processState(int input);
};

#endif // TESTSTATE1_H
```

Here is my main.cpp:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include "state_t.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    state_t *myState = new testState1();

    myState = myState->processState(1);
    myState = myState->processState(2);
    myState = myState->processState(3);
    myState = myState->processState(1);

    return a.exec();
}
```

**Note:** the code all works perfectly, its really a question of "correctness".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Given your particular example**:

It is a bad idea. You introduce a very tight coupling between base and derived types *in the wrong direction*. A base class should know nothing about its derived types. That is one of the things that allows it to be an effective base class. In your current scheme, every time you write a derived type, you would have to touch the header of the base, forcing a compile time dependency on all client code of the base. Besides that, you have a cyclic include dependency.

**In general**:

In non-pathological cases, it depends on the situation. Concerning header files, one could argue that it is good to know which headers are required by a file, in which case it makes sense for them to be at the top. However, if the includes are considered to be implementation details that would only be a distraction, they could be placed at the bottom. In my experience this applies specifically to the implementation of template code, and implementation of helper classes and inline functions in anonymous namespaces.

Comment: I don't think you're answering the question: you are talking about a language/design issue here, the OP is asking about the preprocessor and whether it's ok to put `#include` at the end.

Comment: +1, this is the only correct answer. I've seen includes at the end of a header only in cases where the implementation has to also be in a header, so the implementation (say of members of a class template) goes in to a foo_C.h file (or some such) and is included at the end...

Comment: @FrerichRaabe I read the question. OP is very specific about the context in which they want to use this. They are not asking a general question at all.

Comment: @juanchopanza +1 Infact this is the kind of answer I am looking for... a very good point regarding "breaking ecapsulation" of the base and derived classes, I had not thought of that :) note: This is a general question (all inputs welcome) about a specific implementation/design

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I'd much rather have all the includes at the top.  You can use forward declarations in your other headers to get around the define order issue.

But that's just a style thing - "correctness" wise, there's no reason why you can't do that.  You can validly include anything anywhere you like, it's just likely to cause confusion later!

Comment: +1 for confusion. If I saw it I'd assume there was something particularly special that required the ordering and then waste time hunting for it!

Comment: It doesn't matter where the includes are. It is a bad idea overall.

Comment: Confusing, yes I can agree with that... even to me it looks odd as I mentioned :o

Comment: Note that the base class *cannot* be forward declared, so he can't move these includes to the top...

Answer (score 1):

According to me, this is just a convention, as everybody do that, a *standard* dev will not take a look at the end of the file if he need to add some, and this will be a mess with some includes at the top and some at the bottom.

Comment: Its also a fair point, in a similar way to benjymous' confusion point.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to have my includes at the top otherwise it could be a bit confused. My suggestion for you is do not include teststate1.h and teststate2.h in test_t.h instead create state_all.h

```
#include "state_t.h"
#include "teststate1.h"
#include "teststate2.h"
```

And include state_all.h instead of state_t.h where you need it

Comment: OP uses `statemachine.h` name in his question for this 'solution'.

Comment: Infact this is what I eventually did. Based on the feedback I got I ditched the "includes at the end" and put them into statemachine.h